# Accessing the value of a given cell in a tr array

Tags: jquery

I am getting all the rows of this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QupLN/3/ like

```
var x =  $("tr").map(function(i,j){
return $(j).text();
});
```

I can access an item in that array like

```
console.log(x[1]);
```

`console.log(x[1]);` holds the data of a row i am interested in.However i would like to get the value of each cell in `console.log(x[1]);`

How do i access for instance the firstname value in `x[1];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var x =  $("tr").map(function(i,j){
   return $(j).text();
});

var firstname = x[1].split("\n")[2];
var lastname  = x[1].split("\n")[3];
```

Comment: In the answer you have given,it gets all the table cells data into one giant array and this is no good.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
  $("#tableId tr td:first-child").click(function() {
     $(this).text()
   });
```